# Insert a node after every node that is a sum of next 2 nodes in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

The program should insert a node that is a sum of next 2 nodes

stdin: 2->7->4->9;

stdout: 2->11->7->13->4->9;

The program returns a segmentation fault,I'm not sure what seems to be the problem

```
void insert(Node * list){

   if (list==NULL) {

   return;

    }

for(; (list->next->next)!=NULL ; list=list->next){

 Node* new=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

  if(new == NULL)

   return;

else {

 new->data= (( list->next->next )->data )+( (list->next)-> data );

  new->next = list->next;

   list->next = new;

list = list->next->next ;

     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Check *(list->next->next)!=NULL*.

Comment: `list->next` can be NULL, when you access `list->next->next`.